# print int and int arrays together

Tags: java

```
public int[] solution(int divisor, int[] arr){...}

public static void main (String[] args) {
Index method = new Index();
System.out.println(method.solution(5, 9, 7, 10,5));
    }
```

I want to put it together int, `int[]`
in `method.solution(   )`.

but the following error appears.

I want to make it recognized as `int[]` type,
is there a way?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLVg2.png)

> > I saw the comments and corrected them :)

Comment: `public int[] solution(int divisor, int... arr) {` then in this method, change: `a1.get(i);` to `a1.add(arr[i]);` then make the call: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(method.solution(5, 5, 9, 7, 10, 5)));`. The method `solution()` can accept an int[] array or comma delimited varArgs of integer values.

Comment: Look at @DevilsHnd comment above. I believe this is what you are looking for but it is hard to tell without a description of your goal

Comment: @ggggraceful (or not), you are not supposed to change the main content of your question so that the original answers are of no value.  If you have a new issue then make a new question.  The question is now completely different to the original.

Comment: I'm sorry. I modified it to the code I used for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.ToString(method.solution(5, new int[]{9, 7, 10, 5})));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by

```
public int[] solution(int divisor, int[] arr)
{
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    return arr;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Index method = new Index();
    System.out.println(method.solution(5, new int []{9, 7, 10,5}));
}
```

**output**

```
[9, 7, 10, 5]
[I@15db9742
```

Comment: There is an error saying ' Index 2 out of bounds for length 0'. How can I solve this?

Comment: Not sure where is error is coming from.  The whoe stacktrace would show you. **But** `a1.get(i);` - `a1` is empty and this will fail

Comment: the returned array should be a zero length because no items are added to the arraylist, then answer is reassigned as a new array with size `new int[a1.size()];`

Comment: change `a1.get(i);` in first for loop to a1.add(i)